# Type safe casting to multiple potential types

Tags: haskell

I've currently got a pattern like the following happening in my code (this is simplified from the actual code which is a large GADT dealing with expressions).

```
data I = A | B | C | D

type family TC1 (a :: I) :: Constraint where
  TC1 'A = ()
  TC1 'C = ()
  TC1 _ = ('True ~ 'False)

type family TC4 (a :: I) :: Constraint where
  TC4 'B = ()
  TC4 'C = ()
  TC4 'D = ()
  TC4 _ = ('True ~ 'False)

data T (t :: I) where
  T1 :: (TC1 t) => T t
  T2 :: T B
  T3 :: T t
  T4 :: (TC4 t) => T t
  etc

castL :: (Typeable t) => [Maybe t] -> Maybe t
castL l = case catMaybes l of
  (x:_) -> Just x
  [] -> Nothing

mkT1 :: Typeable a => Maybe (T a)
mkT1 = castL [cast (T1 :: T 'A), cast (T1 :: T 'C)]
```

A few questions:

1. Is there a nicer way to specify a constraint that always fails instead of `('True ~ 'False)`?
2. `mkT1` looks a bit hacky but it does seem to work. Is there a nicer way of doing it?
3. Is there a better way to structure the whole thing (I understand this is a tricky question as I can't include all the detail of what I'm trying to achieve in a reasonably length post, but I'm basically generating a parse tree).

Comment: where is TC used ?

Comment: Whoops in the constructor see edit

Comment: Just to parse the code, speaking out loud: the type T is indexed by kind I. but its value constructor, via the constraints from TC, only allow to create value at type index 'A and 'C. type 'B and 'D can not be index of any value of type TC.

Comment: Yes (I think). The T1 constructor can only have type `T A` or `T C`. There is of course other constructors, I've added a few examples to the code to illustrate this idea.

Comment: now castToT1 attempts to convert a value of type T, indexed by some type a of kind I, to a value of type T indexed by b of kind I, b being provided by the caller of castToT1.

Comment: That's right. Returns Nothing if you can't construct T1 with that type but if you can, returns a T1 of that type. It's like the ordinary `cast` function, but instead of only one valid target there's multiple.

Comment: shouldn't your casts be [ ((cast x) :: T 'A), ((cast x) :: T 'C)] instead ?

Comment: I've removed the `castToT1` and added `mkT1`, this should make things clearer

Comment: no pb. so the caller of mkT1 request a value of type T at type index a, and mkT1 provide them through constructor T1. it's an indexed smart constructor, which might fail as T1 is guarded by TC1 which you have provided.

Comment: Yep that's pretty much it.

Comment: and then since you don't know yet the index which will be requested, you enumerate now the witnesses (values) at all possible indexes, and let cast transform them into the value Nothing if the provided index is different, or Just the same if the index requested will be the same.

Comment: so what you'd want is a way to provide an enumeration of every possible index for which TC1 provide you with empty constraints

Comment: Yes that would be nice although I am open to alternate approaches also.

Comment: Minor point: in the second family we find `TC2` which should read `TC4`, I guess.